# Bubble Sort not sorting

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement bubble sort, but in the end, the list isnt sorted at all.

It looks like this, and I cant find the error:

```
void sort(int values[], int n)
{
    //Printing unsorted list
    for(int l = 0; l < n; l++)
    {
        printf("Unsorted %i \n", values[l]);
    }

    // Implement Bubble sort
    for(int j = 0; j <= n-1; j++)
    {
        int swaps = 0;
        int k = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n - k; i++)
        {
            if(values[i] > values[i+1])
            {
                swap(&values[i], &values[i+1]);
                swaps++;
                printf("swaps: %i\n", swaps);
                //Printing sorted list
                for(int m = 0; m < n; m++)
                {
                    printf("Sorted %i \n", values[m]);
                }
            } 

            if(swaps == 0)
            {
                return;  
            }

            k++; 
        }
    }
}
```

The unsorted list is:

```
Unsorted 34 
Unsorted 17 
Unsorted 51 
Unsorted 12 
Unsorted 33 
Unsorted 56 
Unsorted 11 
Unsorted 31 
Unsorted 16 
Unsorted 55
```

And the sorted list comes out like this:

```
Sorted 17 
Sorted 34 
Sorted 12 
Sorted 33 
Sorted 51 
Sorted 56 
Sorted 11 
Sorted 31 
Sorted 16 
Sorted 55
```

PS: The swap function is working, I tested it already.

Comment: You should walk through the function yourself, line by line; the error is easy to spot, if you know the concept of bubble sort.

Comment: Some people are just not willing to help. If I could find the error on my own, with a debugger or just looking at it, I would NOT have posted here

Comment: @JoaoTurolla some people do not want to work, because it is match easier to ask rather than debugging by yourself. Problem is - you learn how to program only when you work, not when you are getting answers from somebody else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem I see with your code is in

```
    for(int i = 0; i < n - k; i++)
    {
        if(values[i] > values[i+1])
        {
            swap(&values[i], &values[i+1]);
            swaps++;
            printf("swaps: %i\n", swaps);
            //Printing sorted list
            for(int m = 0; m < n; m++)
            {
                printf("Sorted %i \n", values[m]);
            }
        } 
        if(swaps == 0)
        {
           return;  
        }

        k++; 
    }
```

You print all the values inside the `if` statement, which is wrong. And, if the first value is not swapped, then the function will return without doing anything.

A probable solution would be

```
  int swaps = 0;
  for(int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1 ; i++)
    {
        if(values[i] > values[i+1])
        {
            swap(&values[i], &values[i+1]);
            swaps++;
        }
    }
    if(swaps == 0)
    {
      break;  
    }
  } 
  printf("swaps: %i\n", swaps);
  if(swaps == 0)
  {
     return;  
  }
  //Printing sorted list
  for(int m = 0; m < n; m++)
  {
      printf("Sorted %i \n", values[m]);
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, I was printing in the wrong place. But, I didnt get why did you put 
`if(swaps == 0) 
{
    return;
}` 
outside the first loop (the one with J). Because I set mine inside the first loop and outside the second one and it seems to work

Comment: @JoaoTurolla, yes, you are correct there because if there are no swaps in the first iteration of the for loop with the `j`, then there is no need to check the rest of it. I didn't actually compile this and wrote it by looking at the problems I saw ( I mentioned that this is a probable solution, didn't mean it is the most efficient ) which is why I missed that. But now, I compiled it, and also fond a mistake with `k`, you don't need `k`, it will not work for special cases, so I removed it. Look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** 
if `swaps == 0`, this loop still doesn't work. Consider the set `{17, 40, 39, 41}`. No swaps occured for the first element yet it is still unsorted.

Answer (score 0):

i think in there is problem in second loop

soln

```
int temp;
for(int j = 0; j <= n-1; j++)
{
    int swaps = 0;
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n - j; i++)
    {
        if(values[i] > values[i+1])
        {
            temp=values[i];
            values[i]=values[i+1];
            values[i+1]=temp;
            swaps++;
            cout<<"swaps:"<<swaps<<"\n";

        }




    }
}
for(int m = 0; m < n; m++)
            {
                cout<<"Sorted "<<values[m]<<"\n";
            }
```

and also if first no is smaller than second swap variable is defined as zero and program exit